# Need original position number in dictionary

Tags: c#

```
static Int64 binsearch(int first, Int64 target, int last, Dictionary<Int64> mynumbers)
{
        Int32 mid;
        int iteration = 0;

        while (first < last)
        {
            iteration = iteration + 1;
            mid = (first + last) / 2;

            if (mynumbers[mid].Equals(target))
            {
                return mynumbers[mid];
            }

            else if (target < mynumbers[mid])
            {
                last = mid - 1;
            }

            else if (target > mynumbers[mid])
            {
                first = mid + 1;
            }


        }
        return 0;
    }
```

I need the original position number in dictionary

For example (2,5,10,3,1,5,6)

```
0=a[2], 1=a[5], 2=a[10],....
```

and search 10 give me 2

Comment: I don't understand. How will possible `a[10]` will be `2` but `a[5]` will be `1` ?

Comment: Dictionary is a Key,Value pair. Can you compile?

Comment: sorry Soner Gönül,0=2,1=5,2=10

Comment: It seems you need to get elements based on index. `Dictionary` is unordered. You can't access it with index. `OrderedDictionary` does it but unfortunately it is Non-generic

Comment: `Dictionary<Int64>`??? Which class is this? It doesn't exist in .Net, because the .Net `Dictionary<T,T>` requires two generic type parameters.

Comment: What's the point of a binary search on a Dictionary anyway? The whole idea of a Dictionary is that it eliminates the need for this kind of search operation. Binary search only makes sense on list/array like structures, not hashtable structures.

Answer (score 1):

`Dictionary` is not ordered, you can't reliably tell the order in which the values were inserted.

Some approaches that you could try instead:

1. Add the position to the value, something like `Dictionary<long, Tuple<long, int>>`. This way, when you retrieve the value for some key, you would get a tuple that contains the actual value along with the position. Also, you might want to use a custom class instead of `Tuple`.
2. Use a `List<KeyValuePair<long, long>>`. The values in `List` are ordered, so you will be able to find the order of insertion. Searching for the value of a given key would be slow (O(n)), but that might not be a problem for you.